# "Operation not Permitted" for Redis

Tags: python, macos, redis

I am developing on a mac which already have redis installed. by default it doesn't have a `redis.conf` so the default settings were used when I `$ redis-server`

```
# Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'
```

I am trying to use `redis-py` and have the following

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis('localhost')
r.set('foo','bar')
r.get('foo')
```

but got the following error

```
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: operation not permitted
```

I also tried in terminal `$ redis-cli ping`, but then i get the following error

```
(error) ERR operation not permitted
```

I suppose since there is no `redis.conf` the default settings doesn't have a password right? Anyways, I also tried to create a `redis.conf`

```
$ echo "requirepass foobared" >> redis.conf
$ redis-server redis.conf
```

then on another window

```
$ redis-cli
$ redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH foobared
(error) ERR invalid password
```

also modified the second line of the python script to

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, password='foobared')
```

but then I got

```
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: invalid password
```

what could I be doing wrong??? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried passing `password=` ?

Comment: @JonClements: yes I did, sorry that was a typo. fixed in the question. any suggestions? thx

Comment: post your redis configs

Comment: @minovsky how did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without any redis.conf file, Redis uses the default built-in configuration. So the default database file (dump.rdb) and the Append Only File are created in the server directory. Maybe the user running Redis does not have write permission on this dir.

So either you give him the permission, or you define another working directory using a config file.

You'll find a default config file for redis 2.6 [here](https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.6/redis.conf)
You must modify this line in the file:

```
# The working directory.
dir ./
```